# Display output by one sql from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

family table

```
familynumber fistname lastname
10001        A        B
10002        C        D
10003        E        F
10004        G        H
```

phone table

```
familynumber phonenumber description
10001        111         mobile
10001        222         home
10001        333         text
10002        444         text
10003        555         work
10003        666         mobile
```

I need output as

```
familynumber phonenumbers
10001        111, 222, 333
10002        444
10003        555, 666
```

I know it can be done by folowing code

```
$families = mysql_query("select * from family")
while($family = mysql_fetch_assoc($families))
{
    extract($family);
    echo "<td>$familynumber</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    $phones = mysql_query("select * from phone where familynumber = '$familynumber'");
    while($phone = mysql_fetch_assoc($phones))
    {
        extract($phone);
        echo $phonenumber . ", ";
    }
    echo "</td>";

}
```

But I need this output in one sql query.

Comment: look on group_concat http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/

Answer (score 2):

using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT p.familynumber,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.phonenumber ORDER BY p.phonenumber SEPARATOR ",")
AS phonenumbers 
FROM phone p LEFT JOIN family f ON p.familynumber = f.familynumber
GROUP BY familynumber
```

Comment: I also need family table fields

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f.familynumber, GROUP_CONCAT(p.phonenumbers) AS numbers
FROM familytable f, phonetable p
WHERE f.familynumber = p.familynumber
GROUP BY familynumber
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2009/12/A-SWEET-Little-MySQL-Function-GroupConcat.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use a left join.  That is probably what you're looking for
something like:
`SELECT * FROM family LEFT JOIN phone ON family.familynumber=phone.familynumber`

Note: This will return an entire row for each phone number type (so if a family has 3 phone numbers, it will return the families info 3 times).

More on left joins: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Note, there are also Right joins, and Inner joins.  You should learn, and memorize these, they are dispensable.  When you get better at them, look up optimizing joins.  There are some great articles, that can save you precious time.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT familynumber, phonenumbers FROM family AS fml INNER JOIN phone AS ph ON fml.familynumber = ph.familynumber GROUP BY ph.familynumber

I am not sure but this may help you or put you in better position